# Visual Studio Code shows 3 scroll bars when working with Jupyter notebook. Can we have only one scroll bar instead?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ide

Following is a screenshot of VS Code Version 1.43.2 when working with a Jupyter notebook. It shows 3 scrollbars for scrolling. It is confusing when scrolling with 3 scroll bars. Is it possible to get rid of them leaving only one scroll bar?

[image: ter]

Comment: I can confirm this, looks like a bug.